# How to call a model function from another model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to call the listcity function in another model named "property"

/model/Crawler.php

```
class Crawler extends Model {
public function listcity($statename)
  {

    $ins="exec Prc_Lst_CityMaster @CountryName = 'India', @StateName = '".$statename."'";

      return DB::select($ins);
  }
}
```

/model/Property.php

```
use App\Models\Crawler,
class Property extends Model {
 public function __construct(Crawler $Crawler)
    {     
        $this->Crawler = $Crawler;

    }
 public function propertyDetails($id)
    {
$this->Crawler->listcity($id);
}
}
```

But i get an error

ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2):

You should use relationships instead of injecting a model into another model. But if you want to do that, you need to do it manually and not through constructor:

```
public function propertyDetails($id)
{
    app('App\Crawler')->listcity($id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a property for `Crawler` in the model.

```
public $Crawler;

public function __construct(Crawler $Crawler)
{     
      $this->Crawler = $Crawler;
}
```

Comment: If we use this code, we get the following error message SQLSTATE[HY090]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (SQL: )